# Tilemap tearing is occurring within my game build, but is not present in the scene or game view?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As the title says, there is bad tearing and gaps opening between the tiles painted on the separate tilemaps in my game, this has only just begun to occur.

I have already tried turning off AA in quality settings.

Any help would be amazing c:

Pics:

Scene and Gameview of the tilemaps
[image]
How it looks after building the project
[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like tearing to me.  But you can see what you Vsync settings are set to.

Comment: No luck altering Vsync settings I'm afraid, the lines appear to disappear when the camera is zoomed in.